# How to dynamically update which OptionMenus are available

Tags: tkinter

in my code I am prompting for the parameters of a heatmap. Depending on if the x-axis for example is a space dimension or time, I want to update the selected units accordingly. I also want to make it so all axis's can have their dimensions, or number of data-points changed. However, when I select a different parameter in one of my axises menus, the corresponding options don't update.

```
heatwindow = Tk()
heatwindow.geometry('800x800')

def Heatsetting():
    x_axis_var=StringVar(heatwindow)
    Label(heatwindow,text="Variable of x-axis").pack()
    x_axis=OptionMenu(heatwindow,x_axis_var,"x","y","z","t").pack()
    y_axis_var=StringVar(heatwindow)
    Label(heatwindow,text="Variable of x-axis").pack()
    y_axis=OptionMenu(heatwindow,y_axis_var,"x","y","z","t","test").pack()
    held_var=StringVar(heatwindow)
    Label(heatwindow,text="Held Variable").pack()
    held_axis=OptionMenu(heatwindow,held_var,"x","y","z","t").pack()

    if(x_axis_var.get()=="x" or y_axis_var.get()=="x"):
       Label(heatwindow, text="Number of x's").pack()
       nx=Entry(heatwindow,width=7).pack()
       x_var=StringVar(heatwindow)
       x_var.set("cm") #default value
       Label(heatwindow,text="units of x").pack()
       OptionMenu(heatwindow,x_var,"mm","cm","m").pack()

    if(x_axis_var.get()=="y" or y_axis_var.get()=="y"):
       Label(heatwindow, text="Number of y's").pack()
       ny=Entry(heatwindow,width=7).pack()
       y_var=StringVar(heatwindow)
       y_var.set("cm") #default value
       Label(heatwindow,text="units of y").pack()
       OptionMenu(heatwindow,y_var,"mm","cm","m").pack()

    if(x_axis_var.get()=="z" or y_axis_var.get()=="z"):
       zlabel=Label(heatwindow, text="Number of x's")
       zlabel.pack()
       nz=Entry(heatwindow,width=7).pack()
       z_var=StringVar(heatwindow)
       z_var.set("cm") #default value
       Label(heatwindow,text="units of z").pack()
       OptionMenu(heatwindow,z_var,"mm","cm","m").pack()

    if(x_axis_var.get()=="t" or y_axis_var.get()=="t"):
       Label(heatwindow, text="Number of t's").pack()
       nt=Entry(heatwindow,width=7).pack()
       t_var=StringVar(heatwindow)
       t_var.set("sec") #default value
       Label(heatwindow,text="units of t").pack()
       OptionMenu(heatwindow,t_var,"msec","sec","dimensionless").pack()

Heatsetting()
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're using OptionMenu rather than a Combobox?

Comment: Did not even know there was such a thing, I will check it out.

Comment: Although combobox looks nicer, I don't see why it would help me out in this instance.

Comment: They are easier to update than are optionmenus. Maybe I didn't fully understand your question. Are you wanting to change what appears in an optionmenu, or wanting to change which optionmenus are visible?

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statements all run about a millisecond after creating the widgets, well before the user even sees them, much less interacts with them. You need to move all of that logic into a function that gets called when a value is changed by the user.

Comment: Okay I can totally understand that, however, I'm not quite sure how I would prompt a function that would change the widgets on screen. Can I use a command arguement in OptionMenu or as you suggested Combobox?